# ¿Como enviar por correo PDF generado?

Tags: html, pdf, phpmailer

Tengo un formulario donde al enviarlo y recibirlo en otro archivo, se genera un PDF y se envía por correo. Todo me va bien, solamente que lo que no requiero es guardar ese pdf en el servidor. No se si sea posible.

Al parecer la ultima linea  que tengo al generar el PDF es el responsable, si se la quito entonces no se adjunta el PDF generado en el correo.

```
$pdf = $pdf->output("","S");
$file_name = md5(rand()) . '.pdf';

file_put_contents($file_name, $pdf);
```

¿Se puede enviar un PDF generado sin guardarlo en el servidor?

Comment: Diria que guardarlo en el servidor es lo más practico para luego incluirlo en un mail, pero no hace falta que lo conserves despues de mandar el mail, le haces un `unlink($file_name);` y con eso lo borras justo despues de la instrucción `mail()` o lo que uses para enviarlo.

Comment: Nuevamente, muchas gracias! de verdad!. Saludos!